# Have a Thunderbolt port, need DVI to display on monitor

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi, external-display, macbook-air

I have an external monitor which accepts DVI, VGA and HDMI.

I have a MacBook Air which has a Thunderbolt port only.

Can this MacBook Air use the monitor as a secondary display, and what adapter will I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a Thunderbolt to DVI adapter. Or, [Mini DisplayPort to DVI](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A), since Thunderbolt's display connection is essentially the same as Mini DisplayPort.

> The Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter lets you connect an advanced digital monitor […] to a Mac with a Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt port.

[image]

Comment: You can also get a Thunderbolt (Mini DisplayPort) to HDMI cable, in case you think you might want to plug the laptop into TVs at a later point etc.

Comment: Hm, I have that adapter, but the thunderbolt port on my macbook air is smaller. What port is this? micro displayport??

Comment: Feel free to update this answer and add more info, it's Community Wiki. @alexandru

Comment: @RD. You probably don't have a Mini DisplayPort adapter, but a Mini-DVI adapter, which looks somewhat the same, but is a tad larger. Thunderbolt is Thunderbolt, there's no smaller version of that.

Comment: @slhck you are right, it is mini dvi I remember now